# Function that populates a dropdownlist inside a gridview edit template

Tags: asp.net, templates, gridview, drop-down-menu, codeblocks

I am trying to have different options for different user roles. Here is my code:

```
Private Function GetApprovedBy() As String
        If User.Identity.Name = "officer" Then
            Return "Approved by Officer"
        ElseIf User.Identity.Name = "manager" Then
            Return "Approved by Manager"
        Else
            Return String.Empty
        End If
    End Function
```

Then inside my gridview templates I have:

```
  <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ApprovalEdit" runat="server">
                       <asp:ListItem>Rejected</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem Text=<%= GetApprovedBy() %>></asp:ListItem>

                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
```

When I run the page I get

```
"Literal content ('<asp:ListItem Text=') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection'."
```

Is there an alternative way of achieving this? Preferably without a DB.

Thanks in advance!!

Edit: I have also tried

<`asp:ListItem><%= GetApprovedBy() %></asp:ListItem>`

which failed with error 'Code blocks are not supported in this context'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

careful with this: when binding (grid/list/repeater) use `<%#  %>` and not `<%=  %>`

here's an example of what @adrianos says:

```
Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim ddl As DropDownList = CType(e.Row.FindControl("ApprovalEdit"), DropDownList)
        ' and then do the binding or add some items 

    End If
End Sub
```

(vb! aaagghhh my eyes T_T)

Comment: To keep the Rejected ListItem when Data Binding set AppendDataBoundItems="true" where you declared the DropDownList.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a method that runs on the Gridview RowDataBound event.

In that method, search for your drop down list by id. If you find it, check your user type (manager / officer) and add the relevant listItems programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you want is this:

```
<% ddlRooms.Items.Clear();

                       for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
                       {
                           ddlRooms.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString()  , i.ToString()));
                       }
                    %>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRoomsCountToBook" runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

This is the way that I found out to add dynamic elements in an dropdownlist on a view.